# Is it possible to clear apps cache through code | Javascript

Tags: javascript, caching

I want to clear data cache programmatic of my application that is increasing, right now i am clearing from Settings->Applications->Manage Application->My Application->Clear Cache.

Is it possible to do this through code?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I believe it is something like this

```
caches.keys().then(keys => {
    keys.forEach(key => {
        caches.delete(key);
    })
});
```